# Theorem of Complex Analysis and proof

Tags: complex-analysis

So, I am wondering if something like the following is true and a proof if it is true:

> Let us have the function $f$ which is analytic in whole space $\mathbb C$, and if we have at least two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$, for which it holds that they are not in the image of $\mathbb C$ under $f$, then that analytic function is constant.

Comment: Yes, see Picard theorem

Comment: Thank you as you were my brother!(the biggest thanks in my language)